# Phalcon PHP NativeArray accessing multidimensional array using Volt Template

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, phalcon, volt

I was able to add multi language support in Phalcon using the volt template.

But I can't access phalcon multi dimensional NativeArray in volt.

Here is my getTranslation function:

```
private function _getTranslation()
{
    global $config;

    if ( isset($config[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']]['language']) ) {
        $language = $config[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']]['language'];
    } else if ( $this->session->get('auth') ) {
        $language = "pt";
    } else {
        //Ask browser what is the best language
        $language = $this->request->getBestLanguage();
    }

    //Check if we have a translation file for that lang
    if (file_exists(__DIR__ . "/../translations/".$language.".php")) {
       require __DIR__ . "/../translations/".$language.".php";
    } else {
       // fallback to some default
       require __DIR__ . "/../translations/en-US.php";
    }

    //Return a translation object
    return new \Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\NativeArray(array(
       "content" => $messages
    ));
}
```

Then I setvar:

```
$this->view->setVar("t", $this->_getTranslation());
```

Which will load a translation file with something like this:

```
$messages = array(
"pages" => array(
    "index" => array(
        "title" => "CREATE YOUR ACCOUNT TODAY",
        "call_to_action" => "Join Now!",
        "search_title" => "Find:",
        "search_option" => "I Want To:",
        "search_type" => "Type:",
        "search_where" => "Located On:",
        "search_button" => "GO",
    )
);
```

In the volt template I would like to access something like

```
$t['pages']['index']['call_to_action']
```

Which in volt could be:

```
<div class="call_to_action">{{ t._('pages').('index').('call_to_action') }}</div>
```

But this doesn't work!

Is there any way to access the NativeArray multi dimensional elements within volt template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

For more information refer twig [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation)

```
{{ dump(t['pages']['index']['call_to_action']) }}
```

Output Example:

```
string 'Join Now!' (length=9)
```

Comment: Actually just using {{ t['pages']['index']['call_to_action'] }} worked!!! Thanks Raj